# Ant ReplaceRegExp task - multiple substitutions per file?

Tags: regex, ant

I'm using the Ant ReplaceRegExp task to replace text in over 10,000 files. Each file has multiple search/replace patterns I need to perform. As of right now, have multiple  blocks, each with a FileSet of "**/*.java".

As my list of things to search/replace grows, this takes forever to run since it will do ReplaceRegExp #1 on 10k files, then ReplaceRegExp2 on 10k files, and so on. I already have about 15 ReplaceRegExp blocks, so my task is already taking about 45 minutes.

Is there a way to get it so each file is processed/accessed only once, and it performs all 15+ of my regex search/replaces on the file rather than the file having to be processed 15+ individual times?

In essence, looking for something that is logically like this:

```
    <replaceregexp  
        match="firstmatch"  
        replace="firstraplce"

        match="secondmatch"
        replace="secondreplace"

        etc..

        byline="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </replaceregexp>
```

That's obviously invalid XML, but shows conceptually what I'm looking for. Now I use 2  groups - one for "firstmatch/firstreplace" and one for "secondmatch/secondreplace" on the same set of files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
 <filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
        <replacestring from="oldstr1" to="newstr1"/>
        <replacestring from="oldstr2" to="newstr2"/>
    </tokenfilter>
 </filterchain>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [TokenFilter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#tokenfilter) from [FilterChain and FilterReader](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html), it allows to define a tokenizer (a line tokenizer in your case) and a set of filter that will be applied in sequence. Don't know if it has better performance than calling n times ReplaceRegExp task, but you should try :

```
<filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
        <replaceregex pattern="match_1" replace="replace_1"/>
        <replaceregex pattern="match_2" replace="replace_2"/>
        ...
        <replaceregex pattern="match_n" replace="replace_n"/>
    </tokenfilter>
</filterchain>
```

Comment: this returns an error: **tokenfilter doesn't support the nested "replaceregexp" element**

Comment: @Heinz Thanks for pointing out this error, it was a typo... I have corrected the example, and it works now...